# High precision timer in C# for synchronization objects time-out

Tags: c#, .net, windows, timer

I have something resembling the following code:

```
public void acquireReaderLock(int nmsMaxWait)
{
    //'nmsMaxWait' = timeout in milliseconds

    if(_mutex.WaitOne(nmsMaxWait))
    {
        //Need time left for the second wait?
        if(_semaphore.WaitOne(???)
        {
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("Timed out");
    }
    else
        throw new Exception("Timed out");
}
```

I am looking for a high-precision timer. In C++ I would've used [GetTickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [GetSystemTimeAsFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) APIs to measure the time elapsed, but what should I use in C#?

Comment: Any reason you're not using the [ReaderWriterLockSlim Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx)?

Comment: @dtb: No support for named locks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may think of using a [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) a most acurate timing class in `CLR`, that we use usually in code execution measurments.

But there is also other timing options like: [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) class, that can be used too.

As @Matthew Watson mantioned, there is another option again: using [Environment.TickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx).

Comment: I would also use Stopwatch, but it's worth mentioning [Environment.TickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx) which is the same as GetTickCount()

Comment: +1. Although I think the mention of `System.Timers.Timer` here is inappropriate. Timers are used for executing things on a schedule. They're not much good for measuring elapsed time.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that `StopWatch` comes with such high resolution. That should do it.